# Kill background running job in subprocess from main process

Tags: bash, kill, jobs, pid

I wanna create 5 children `function otrok {...}` and run them in background. Children are writing in `mkfifo $kanal`. After all children are done writing I wanna kill `tail` process.

Basically this code works as expected, except I don't know how to get `tail PID`.

```
( tail -f $kanal >> cats & )
for i in $(seq 1 5); do
    ( otrok $i ) &
done
wait #wait for all "( otrok $i ) &" to exit
#DOTO #kill tail in first line
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply kill the first background job:

```
kill %1
```

---

If you want it that way, the pid of the tail command can be obtained using:

```
tail -f "$kanal" >> cats &
pid=$!
```

(Note: You don't need a sub shell to run the tail in backround)

---

Also note that you can save the `seq` command in bash. Simply use

```
for i in {1..5} ; do
    ...
```

Comment: This kill job with job ID 1, but tail isn't job because is started from subprocess... If I don't use sub shell then `wait` will wait till inf., because tail never ends

Comment: Can I return pid from sub shell? like this `(tail &; exit &!); PID=$?`

Comment: You can `wait %1` or even `wait "$pid"`. (Having tail's pid saved in `$pid` like I showed). You don't need a sub shell! `wait %1` would be the best..

Comment: you don't need sub shells. what is so hard to understand with that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71197/discussion-between-matjaz-mav-and-hek2mgl).

Comment: Depends on the shell and its mode also. I would expect `wait %1` to work in an interactive Bash, but maybe fail in a script and definitely if the shell is `sh`